# Passing value from interactive report to editting modal dialog results in incorrect values in select list LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am having some difficulties with passing values from an interactive report, populated by a simple SQL query, to an ‘Edit’ modal dialog. I selected ‘Link to Custom Target’ which specifies a modal dialog page in the application, under the ‘Link’ section of the ‘Attributes’ tab for the interactive report to enable editing. I used ‘Set Items’ to populate the dialog with the existing values as show in the images below.

I am using the slashes to escape columns that may contain special characters. However, when I open the record to modify APEX appears to populate the field with a ‘copy’ of the value that does not exist in the list of values as shown below.If I go to save the record using these ‘copy fields’ I get 'invalid numeric value' error. Fields such as Material and Capital/Maintenance are stored in the table as numerical values and the drop downs are based on a ‘select list’ with a LOV. Could anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or what I need to change to address this error?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Fields such as Material and Capital/Maintenance are stored in the table as numerical values and the drop downs are based on a ‘select list’ with a LOV.

Did you correctly set LoV's query? Generally speaking, it is supposed to return two columns: **display** and **return** value, e.g.

```
select material_name as display_value,
       material_code as return_value   --> this is a NUMBER, as you said
from materials
```

Maybe you used the same column for both display and return value? LoV would still "work" (display the list), but submit would then fail. Hm?